# mysql_real_escape more than once

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I was just wondering whether it makes a difference if I mysql_real_escape data more than once?

So if I escaped data in one part of my website, and then again in another part of code. Would this be a problem? Or make a difference?

Comment: why not to just try it and print the result out?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is not an idempotent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You'd get extra unnecessary backslashes.

Answer (score 8):

The right place for mysql_real_escape is **right before** you send the query to save the data.
Every other instance anywhere else in the script is a major design flaw.

That should preferably in an own db-class of course.

Comment: It's the right place to do it, but not the best way to handle the problem.

Comment: @Blair care to explain a little? What problem and what's the best?

Comment: The problem of handling injection. Parametrised queries are a better way of dealing with that. But like I said, your answer gives the right place to do what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be a problem.

For example:
if *a* is "Joe's House", the first call will produce "Joe\'s House" and the second one will produce "Joe\\\'s House", saving the backslash in the database.

This is similar to the problem that arises when the web server has the magic quotes enabled and you use mysql_real_escape_string on input from the client. This is solved by:

```
if (! get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["value"]);
} else {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET["value"])); 
}
```

(For the latter example see http://www.php.net/get_magic_quotes_gpc )

[I edited the answer to reflect corrections in the comments below]

Comment: Magic quotes do not perform the same escaping as mysql(i)_(real)_escape string. The right way to handle magic quotes, if you are unable to disable them, is to remove them with stripslashes, and then apply escaping if necessary (i.e., if you can't use parameterized queries). Ideally, you'd get rid of magic quotes at the very beginning, to avoid having to strip them every time you need to output them in a non-DB context.

Comment: I won't downvote because of your score, but this approach is wrong. Escaping should be just `$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["value"]);` **unconditional**. And getting rid of magic quotes is another matter that should be done far before query composing, at the very top of the script.

Comment: I'll have to downvote you if you don't do `$value = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET["value"]));` on the last condition.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know that. And thanks for the information, I will correct my code too :-)

Comment: @Alix but this approach is wrong too. Just leave database escaping alone. It has nothing to do with magic quotes. Maguc slashes must be just stripped off, for the many reasons. Don't your app consists only of this very line?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I know it's wrong and I don't expect him to provide a solution for magic quotes in his answer but since he is checking for it the least he can do is provide equally good code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to distinguish between an escaped and an unescaped string, because the thing which looks like an escaped string was the intended unescaped string. Therefore, trying to escape again, would escape the escaping - and the escaped-once text will be what MySQL reads.

Therefore, you should never escape more than once.

However, a better solution is to use paramterized queries, since then you don't need to escape at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be an over-escapement problem.  This is the same for any escaping, regardless of what exactly it does.  For instance, if you'd escape double quotes in string following common rule:

```
bla "foo"
```

after one escaping becomes

```
bla \"foo\"
```

after two becomes

```
bla \\\"foo\\\"
```

and so on.  Number of "unescapements" must exactly match number of "escapements".  You could see manifestations of this problem on some sites that over-escape some characters in text fields, so that simple apostrophe becomes `\'` on output.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, data would be double-escaped.

You should not use `mysql_real_escape()` at all, parameterized queries via [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) have been sticking around long enough.

Comment: @ whoever downvoted this: An explanation would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes a difference:

```
$string = "I'm Chuck!";
mysql_escape_string($string); // I\'m Chuck!
mysql_escape_string(mysql_escape_string($string)); // "I\\\'m Chuck!
```