# From php special char is not inserted into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CBage"  id="cbage2" value="and age >= 18 and age <= 24" checked/><label for="cbage2">18-24</label>
```

value="and age >= 18 and age <= 24"

After post action in php (i have tried)

```
$age1 = $_POST['CBage'];
$age = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(",", $age1));
```

or

```
 $age = implode(",", $age1);
```

Table is created as

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
`age` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

In mysql it insert as

```
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('$age')
```

The value inserted as follows

```
and age = 18 and age,and age = 25 and age,
```

The problem is that it doesn't insert the value correctly (its missing > < and some text in the end) as

```
"and age >= 18 and age <= 24" but rather it inserted as "and age = 18 and age,and age = 25 and age,"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843849/mysql-real-escape-more-than-once) try to use htmlentities()

Comment: No it isn't missing those characters; your'e looking at the value in a web browser, which treats them as special characters in the html markup.... do a "view source" to see what is really being retrieved from the database

Comment: ok first of all you shouldn't use mysql_ use PDO or MYSQLI instead. try to paste a full code to help better understanding of your issue

Comment: try to use htmlentities it will take care of all special charecters   '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'   '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;' then to reverse it when fetching use html_entity_decode

Answer (score 0):

try to use htmlentities it will take care of all special charecters   '<' (less than) becomes '<'   '>' (greater than) becomes '>' then to reverse it when fetching use html_entity_decode

`'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'   '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'` then to reverse it when fetching use html_entity_decode

moreover its important to stop using Mysql_ to avoid serious sql injection danger
use PDO or Mysqli prepared statements

```
$var1=htmlentities ($_POST['var1'])   ;


 $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table(field1) VALUES (?)');

    $sth->bindParam(1, $var1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
```

to fetch back

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table');

while($row = $sth ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo html_entity_decode($row['field1']); //etc...
}
```